# Allow special character in CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter, utf-8, character-encoding, character

I have problem: if I use `preg_replace` with plain PHP, it works. However in CodeIgniter, it doesn't work. I've searched and did some changes such as: make general UTF-8, set `$config['permitted_uri_chars']`, use `header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');` and use `meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"`...

...but none of those fixed the problem.

Example:

```
$text='namé';
echo $text;
```

and the result is

```
nam�
```

The last character in that string isn't being rendered properly.

Can anyone help or point me in the right direction as to how to allow writing special characters in CodeIgniter?

Answer (score 0):

**solution:**

```
$text='namé';
$decoded= utf8_decode($text);
echo $decoded;
```

**output:**

```
namé
```

Comment: what meta http header are you using? I'm using <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /> and it works for me

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title></title>

 <style type="text/css">

Comment: and i use this after <body> view/view.php

</head>
<body>
<?php
 header('Content-type : text/html; charset=utf-8'); 
?>

<div id="header" align="center">
<div id="container" align="left">

Please help me :(

Comment: what version of CI are you running? Try and download the current version - and do a CLEAN install - then just try my solution above - its working for me...

Comment: i've try a fresh copy but didn't work and I use your method for unicode but the result is '?'..... Please how solve this

Comment: is this on a local server, or on a real server? perhaps try on another server - maybe its your PHP settings?

Comment: a local server
i use this but same to
str_replace("é","&#233;", $teks

Comment: so have you tried on another server? like I said - the solution above works for me on a clean CI install - so that implies that it is more likely your server and some php setting...